# Matrix Multiplication Throwing SubScript Out of Range Error

Tags: vba, excel, matrix-multiplication

Preface: Messing around with cube math and after looking around at all the various options I seem to have run into an issue with my current structure. Maybe someone would love to point out what I am missing here?

```
Private Sub cube3()
    Dim x(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Single
    Dim y(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Single
    Dim z(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Single
    For a = 0 To 2
        For b = 0 To 2
            Count = (Count + 3) / 2 * 1.5
            x(a, b) = Count
            y(a, b) = Count
            z(a, b) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(x, y)(a, b) '****** This is where the issue occurs
            Debug.Print ; x(a, b)
            Debug.Print ; z(a, b)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: wouldn't it be `...MMult(x(a,b),y(a, b))`?  But the fact that you are multiplying only one number in each array at a time wouldn't you get the same answer by `= x(a,b)*y(a, b)`?

Comment: @ScottCraner you know I am not entirely sure. I just started messing with this to be honest. If you have some suggestions to help me learn this I am all ears buddy.

Comment: though i'll say that x(a,b)*y(a,b) did the trick.

Comment: if ya want to post as answer ill give you the feedback you deserve.... unless you really want to elaborate on something I might want to know :D

Comment: I am playing with it as we speak.  I do not use the MMULT() function and am trying to understand it.

Comment: Awesome. It was my first time running into it and haven't gotten it to work properly (even as a worksheet function) but I must admit I was most likely not using it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance `MMULT()` is not the way to go it is not made for single value multiplication.

It systematically does something similar to SUMPRODUCT().  As it multiplies each item in a row in the First array with each item in a column in the second array.

[image]

Becomes

[image]

See [HERE](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Mmult-Function.html) for a much better explanation.

---

In this code you are multiplying single values so a simple multiplication would work:

```
= x(a,b)*y(a, b)
```

As far as my research has found to multiply each value in one array with its sister value in a second array, the only method is to loop.

You are already using the quickest method by which to do this.  By using array instead of worksheet ranges even with larger datasets this will still be pretty quick.

---

If you want to use the MMULT() then fill both arrays first and declare z as a variant:

```
Private Sub cube3()
Dim x(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Single
Dim y(0 To 2, 0 To 2) As Single
Dim z
For a = 0 To 2
    For b = 0 To 2
        Count = (Count + 3) / 2 * 1.5
        x(a, b) = Count
        y(a, b) = Count

        Debug.Print x(a, b)
        Debug.Print y(a, b)
    Next
Next
 z = Application.WorksheetFunction.MMult(x(), y()) '****** This is where the issue occurs
 Range("A1").Resize(UBound(z, 1), UBound(z, 2)).Value = z
End Sub
```

Comment: This does technically answer my question. I will keep messing with different approaches as I am sure there is an easier way to fill "Z" with the matrix multiplication of (x,y) without having to do each step individually as I am quite certain that would be performance hindering if I was working with larger data sets.

Comment: Effing bad ass dude. My issues were 1) trying to declare z parameters and 2) inappropriate understanding of how to implement MMULT correctly. thanks for helping me along there!

Comment: @DougCoats thanks for finding something from which I can learn something new.

Comment: glad I could help :D

Comment: The really cool thing about this BTW is that we have learned two useful approaches 1 fill array while going, or 2 bulk dump at end. Is there any usefulness to filling it as you go? I dont think there would be but I am still somewhat of a novice and figure its worth knowing anyway? I guess its worth knowing how to do it manually for funzies

Comment: @DougCoats if you can get away with the bulk load then do it that way.  Never fill an array with values from a consecutive worksheet range.  Load in bulk `z=Range("A1:D20").Value` declare z as a variant or it will throw an error and realize that z will be base 1 not 0.  But loading an array from an array by looping really does not take that long.  I have done over 50,000 loops to load arrays from other arrays with lots of logic and it took a second or two, compared to doing the same using worksheet ranges that took 30 to 40 minutes.

Comment: Yea I was assuming that the cardinal sin of directly manipulating workbooks was to be strictly adhered to if at all possible. But I guess in the event of only working in the background there really isnt too much of a difference i guess. Cool thanks dude